# angular date format gotcha

Tags: angularjs, date, angular-filters

I don't understand what is happening with date in angular world

I have create same date and trying to display them in local or UTC but getting unexpected result

**UPDATE:**

1. I want to know are the actual value and display value same in following cases?
2. why adding timezoe to date filter does not do anything?
3. if I want to create date and set hour to 12 PM UTC and to be display locally what is the correct way.
4. is it possible to create an specific date with hour set 12 in UTC and always display in UTC (not local timezone)

   ```
   //template
   <div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <p>expecting date in local time {{date1}} </p>
   <p>expecting date in local time along with time offset{{date1 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a Z' }} </p>
   <p>expecting date in UTC time along with time offset{{date1 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a Z': 'UTC'}}</p>
   <p>expecting date in local time {{date1 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a': 'UTC'}}</p>
   <p>expecting time to be -10 hour from UTC {{date1 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a ': '-1000'}}</p>

   <p>Expecting it to be in UTC: {{date2}}</p>
   <p>Expecting it to be in UTC same as above {{date2 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a': 'UTC'}}</p>
   <p>Expecting it to be -10 from UTC {{date2 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a': '-1000'}}</p> 
   <p>expecting it to be +12 from utc {{date4 |date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a': 'UTC'}}</p>

   </div>
   ```

   and following is my controller

   ```
   // controller
   function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
   $scope.date1 = new Date("2017-12-13");
   $scope.date2 = new Date(2017,11,13).toISOString();    
   $scope.date3 = new Date(2017,11,13);
   $scope.date4= new Date($scope.date2).setHours(12)

   console.log('date1',$scope.date1);
   console.log('date2', $scope.date2);
   console.log('date3', $scope.date3);
   console.log('date4', $scope.date4);

   console.log($filter('date')($scope.date2, 'medium'));

   }
   ```

   [Fiddle][1]

   [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/sohail85/bzwoxtw2/

Comment: *"getting unexpected result "* ... what are you expecting and how does it differ? See [ask]

Comment: @charlietfl: I have updated my question